# "Move" waveform "up"/"down"?

Tags: post-production, audio-restoration

When I listened to some music files of an old game, I noticed a strange sounding popping in my headphones. I opened the file in Adobe Audition 3 to see if I could fix the problem.

I found out that the popping comes from up- or down-"shifted" wave forms:

[image]

Question: Is there a way to fix this problem, by somehow "shift" the wave form back to the center?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can definitely fix the majority of the pop on that one by effectively removing the DC offset that is in there.

Most DAWs will let you do this - it can be a bit fiddly, but the aim is to zoom in as much as you can to see where the DC offset starts, and remove it. From your graph it looks like it was suddenly applied to both channels and then ramped down to a much lower level, then removed.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. "DC Bias" is the thing I was looking for. I could repair the file. In case someone has the same problem, here is what I did with Adobe Audition 3: Copy-paste the damaged section into a new file. Apply "normalize" with setting "only DC bias correct", nothing else. Delete from the section of the original file (important!) and insert the corrected section. Simply paste over the selected section (like in Microsoft Word) does not work, since Audition somehow tries to smoothen the inserted section.